# cryptojs sha256 hash length getting 64 bit instead of 32 bit

Tags: sha256, cryptojs

I am using the crypto js from the https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/

I am facing an issue as the **.NET** generated `sha256 hash` is 32 bit but the hash generated with the cryptojs is 64 bit ..

Please advice how to get the 32 bit hash from cryptojs `sha256` algorithm.

```
CryptoJS.SHA256("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx..").toString()
```

Comment: Sha256 produces a 256bit hash, so not sure what you mean about the about being 32 or 64bit. Perhaps you could clarify with an example?

Comment: Don't confuse bits with bytes. There is a difference. Also, don't confuse bytes with characters. `CryptoJS.SHA256("").toString()` returns a 256 bit result (32 byte), which is Hex-encoded by default and therefore 64 characters long.